# Power BI Javascript integration. Get Access Token

Tags: javascript, angularjs, powerbi, adal.js

I am trying to integrate PowerBI into my web application. Here is the code I have used

```
 window.config  = {
      instance: 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/',
      tenant: 'common', //COMMON OR YOUR TENANT ID

      clientId: 'my client IS', //This is your client ID
      redirectUri: 'http://localhost:4200/Redirect', //This is your redirect URI

      callback: userSignedIn,
      popUp: true
    };

    var ADAL = new AuthenticationContext(config);

    function signIn() {
      ADAL.login();
    }

    function userSignedIn(err, token) {
      if (!err) {

        showWelcomeMessage();

        ADAL.acquireToken("https://analysis.windows.net/powerbi/api", function (error, token) {
          console.log(error, 't', token);
          // Handle ADAL Error
          if (error || !token) {
            console.log('ADAL Error Occurred: ' + error);
            return;
        }




    function getDataSets(){


      var trythis = "Bearer " + token;
      var request = new XMLHttpRequest();

      request.open('GET', 'https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/datasets');

      request.setRequestHeader('Authorization', trythis);

      request.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (this.readyState === 4) {
          console.log('Status:', this.status);
          console.log('Body:', this.responseText);
        }
      };

      request.send();


    }




    function showWelcomeMessage() {
      var user = ADAL.getCachedUser();
      var divWelcome = document.getElementById('WelcomeMessage');
      divWelcome.innerHTML = "Welcome " + user.profile.name;
    }
```

After login when I tried to get access token I am getting this error
"Token renewal operation failed due to timeout"

can anyone tell me how to get access token of Power BI

Answer (score 0):

Try clearing your browser cache and deleting all of your cookies to see if that error goes away. Also, test in other browsers to see if you still see the same message. A lot of times this error only occurs in Internet Explorer.

For access tokens in PowerBi, see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/developer/walkthrough-push-data-get-token